# Access project's config file from the reference project (dll)

Tags: c#

I am working on a solution where I have couple of projects(Project 1,2,3). Project1 contains the methods for access the Blob storage in azure. Project1 is then referred in Porject2 and Project3.

Problem is, I Project 2 and Project 3 have their own Blob storage connect details which I am storing in config file. I am planning Project1 as a framework hence I want it to pick the detail once its referred.

Eg:
When Project1 dll is added to Project 2. Project1 should read the web.config file of Project2 and get the details.

Project1 -> class lib 
Project2 -> MVC Application
Project3 -> MVC Application

if the approach or my idea is wrong how else can I make it.?

Comment: Not sure I follow but the short of it is this: There is only 1 web.config that is ever loaded and that is the root config in the web directory for the deployed web application. So you should not think of it as reading another projects `web.config`, whatever is loaded just reads **the** `web.config` .(*you can nest web.config files in directories to override values/provide more info but that is a side topic and not relevant to your question*).

Comment: You can always pass the setting to the dll simply create a method for modifying the properties.

Comment: If you only use System.Configuration namespace, then project1 is reading from the web.config file from its top web app project. When it is used in project2 it loads project2's web.config. The same applies to project3. What's the problem you met exactly? I didn't see a valid question.